# Python: Merging Multiple Sheets into one Workbook

Tags: python, pandas, automation, operating-system

I am trying to merge multiple workbooks into one. However, I am currently having issues regarding my code.

```
cwd = os.path.abspath(r'C:\xxx\xxx\Documents\xxx\xx Data') 
files = os.listdir(cwd) 
print (files)
df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
     if file.endswith('.csv'):
         df = df.append(pd.read_excel(file), ignore_index=True) 
df.head()
```

This code returns an error on line 7.

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Code.csv'

Can anybody help me as I am not sure how/why cant it find the file.

[Folder Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoANl.png)

Comment: Why `read_excel` for csv files? I just tested your code and it works fine.

Comment: I changed it to read_csv. Really? smh Its not working for me.. Maybe I am overlooking a small detail somewhere

Comment: Did you just literally copy paste the code then just change the location?

Comment: Yes, exact copy except for the location and changing `read_excel` to `read_csv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screenshot of your folder doesn't seem to have a .py file. I'm assuming it's in another folder.

Try

```
os.chdir(cwd)
```

before the for loop.

EDIT -
Alternatively, if you do not want to change your working directory, you can specify the path to the file.

```
pd.read_csv(cwd+"/"+file)
```